# horizontal wordpress theme jQuery left and right buttons

Tags: jquery, wordpress, horizontal-scrolling

I am building a wordpress theme where the posts are lined up horizontally in a wide "container" (similar to “the Shelf" https://demo.thethemefoundry.com/shelf-theme/ ).
Each post is 1160px wis

To click through the posts a jQuery button is used.

But mine moves over not once, but many times. I guess it moves it for every post that's loaded into the loop.
Does anyone have a solution?, I am very new to JavaScript, thanks.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#leftbutton").click(function(){
            $("#container").animate({'left':'+=1160px'});
        });
        $("#rightbutton").click(function(){
            $("#container").animate({'left':'-=1160px'});
        });
    });
    </script>
```

see the example posted on:
http://www.ansikun.com/zarif/news-reviews

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet is correct (or I haven't checked it). The problem is because you're adding it multiple times to your page (once for each post), so clicking the button once moves it n times (where n is the number of posts).

Just add it once to the bottom of your page.

Comment: i added it to the header instead, Now it does what it should:
http://zarifnyc.com/category/news/

But, i am trying to hide the back button on the first post, and next on last.
i tried this:

    $(document).ready(function() {
     if ($('.scrollbox').is({'left':'==0px'})) {
    $('#leftbutton').hide();
     } 
    });

not working
also, since i added the jQuery, the background pictures sometimes disappear in firefox.

javascript is completely new to me, so there might be a better approach all together...

Comment: i might copy this site's java and try to make that horizontal: http://www.dbworks.pro/

Comment: got a little further, now biting my nails on the "if" statement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807731/jquery-slider-left-and-right-buttons-firefox-doesnt-work