# jQuery slider left and right buttons, firefox doesn't work

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming, wordpress, jquery-ui-slider

i made this wordpress theme that displays the loop horizontally:
http://zarifnyc.com/category/news/

```
<Script>
var curx = $('#blog').css(''); 
if(curx <= 0) {hide('#leftbutton')} else {show('#leftbutton')}
if(curx >= 25000) {hide('#rightbutton')} else {show('#rightbutton')}

$(function() 
{
  $('#rightbutton').click(function() {
$('#blogbox').animate({"left" : '-=1070px'});
return false;
});
  $('#leftbutton').click(function() {
$('#blogbox').animate({"left" : '+=1070px'});
return false;
});
  });
</script>
```

...it worked until i try to add an "if" statement to hide the left button on the first post, and right on the last (or use infinite scroll).

'just started to learn jQuery, so any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: do you need the `+=` in the animate? i would think you'd only need the value.

Comment: then the function would only animate once

Comment: UPDATE: making the scrollbox into an id took care of the firefox bug.